# Getting too much zero while reading binary files in

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fread

I'm doing a program that read the whole binary file (in my case, a picture), reading 2 by 2 bytes and printing how many times each byte (from 0000h to FFFFh) appear in the file, but I'm having an issue regarding the quantity of zeros I'm capturing. Don't know exactly if it's a common case, but I'm feeling there's something wrong by allocating the array. There's something like:

bit occuurrences

0 62354

1   13

2   4

3   5

4   2

5   2

6   0

7   2

.   .

.   .

65535 0

What do you guys think I'm doing wrong?

Follow the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
unsigned short int *n;
int cont=0;
long lsize,i,j;

FILE *arq=fopen("C:\\Users\\NB\\Documents\\Testes Allegro\\Trabalho PAQ\\imagens\\426.png","rb");
FILE *out=fopen("saida.csv","w");

fseek(arq,0,SEEK_END);
lsize=ftell(arq);
rewind(arq);

n=(unsigned short int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned short int)*lsize);
fread(n,sizeof(short int),lsize,arq);
fprintf(out,"bit,quantidade\n");
for(i=0x0000;i<=0xffff;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<lsize;j++)
    {
        if(n[j]==i)
            cont++;
    }
fprintf(out,"%li,%d\n",i,cont);
printf("%li,%d-",i,cont);
cont=0;
}
fclose(arq);
fclose(out);
free(n);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating short ints but measuring & reading bytes.  Your array `n` will not work in the way you want.  You will need to size `n` to `lsize/2` times (+ an edge case for odd sizes) and adjust your loop accordingly.

Your looping is very inefficient too!

Comment: You're absolutely right! A short int is a 2-byte data type, so I mean... I think it's a right way to do it. Therefore, I could understand why the array has a _lsize/2_ size, as lsize is the total of bytes of the file. Thank you very much for your clarification! How could I improve the looping line?

Comment: Well depending on what exactly you are trying to do, I would declare an array of 65536 integers, zero them, then read the file in integer by integer incrementing the array at the index of the int you read.